# How to write to console/log in VC++ in a Metro app?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

i am working on vc++ application ,in this application How to write to console/log?

c# ----system.diagnostics.debug.writeline("Hello");
similar to 
Vc++ ----?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A metro style app cannot have a console.  You can use OutputDebugString() in a C++/CXX app to display debug text on the Visual Studio Output window, just like System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write does in a managed app.  There are not a lot of approved winapi functions but OutputDebugString() is okay.  Starting MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205755.aspx).

Comment: In a Metro app there is no System::Diagnostics namespace :|

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a GUI application, you can enable the console by yourself.

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w+t", stdout);
```

and then, you can simple std::cout or printf your diagnostic messages.